# Municipal datasets?

Tags: dataset

I'm looking for some data to create lookup tables with. Specifically, all the counties in each state in the US, and all the cities in each county.

Where might I find municipal datasets like this?

EDIT: I'm looking at census.gov and this appears like it may be the ticket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.census.gov/statab/www/ccdb.html

Look in the "Selected features..." section where there are numerous Excel and PDF downloads

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Zip Code Download](http://www.zipcodedownload.com/) in the past for such a database. I'd recommend the Commercial version since you are looking for the cities and counties.