# Where can I Find XML List of USA Cities and States?

Tags: xml, excel

Can anyone share? Excel format is fine too.

Comment: How is this related to programing?

Comment: Overlaps with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764693/municipal-datasets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, this is a cleaned up version of the 2000 US Census.

Link to article:
http://mhinze.com/archive/list-of-us-cities-all-city-names-and-states-regex-groups/

Direct link:
http://mhinze.com/static-content/cities.txt

It should be easy to just copy/paste this into excel, and do a "Text to Columns" command using Deliminated by Comma.

Comment: Note: This is CSV, which can be imported into Excel.

Comment: Thanks Person-B. I updated the answer to reflect how to do this.

Comment: Links are dead now :(

Answer (score 0):

There's a great basic version here for $20
http://www.zipcodedownload.com/Products/Product/Z5Basic/Standard/Overview/